# Spring: How to get spring applicationContext in a Testng test class, if I can NOT extend AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests

Tags: java, spring, testng, integration-testing

My test already extends an abstract BaseIntegrationTest class, so can't `extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` class - as we normally do with Testng Spring integration tests, and I don't want my BaseIntegrationTest to load the spring application context (by `extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`) because there are a lot more sub-class tests that don't need the context (which has a DB entity), and most of the time I will exclude current test that requires the DB connection for integration test. So once in a while I need to run this Testng based test, which extends some class already and still needs to contextAware (I have tried `implements ApplicationContextAware` which doesn't work for me, maybe I was doing it it wrong?). How would you do it?

Answer (score 2):

That's just how Spring integrates with TestNG - you have to extend  `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`. Alternatively you can manually instantiate Spring in your tests:

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context1.xml", "context2.xml")
```

But that won't allow you to use other kind of annotations like `@Transactional`. Potentially you could write your own integration with Spring over TestNG listeners (hm.. why Spring didn't use it instead?), but that's going to take some time to implement and debug :)

Also, I'd like to mention that **extending your own base classes is not a good idea**. Though it's very common unfortunately. A much better (easier to read, OOP-friendlier) way would be to create separate classes and functions with your common logic. And then invoke those explicitly in your tests.